# Azure Webjob stops for no reason

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have an continuous webjob that is supposed to run until I stop it. I rely on this condition, but for some reason this phenomena happens to me:

```
[01/19/2021 09:57:51 > 44ab83: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob
[01/19/2021 09:57:51 > 44ab83: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[01/19/2021 09:57:56 > 44ab83: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
[01/19/2021 09:57:57 > 44ab83: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[01/19/2021 09:57:57 > 44ab83: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
```

The code didn't throw any error so I'm wondering why is the webjob restarting on its own.
What does `Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob` mean?
I'm not creating/writing any files inside the WebJob's directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Troubleshooting automatic restart/refresh of Azure Web Jobs**

## Solutions 1:

***Reason 1:***

```
Due to website shutdown/restart
```

***Reason 2:***

```
Due to changes in the azure web job directory files or file content (`D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous\<WebJobName>`)
```

***Reason 3:***

```
Due to a web app and/or web job deployment
```

***Reason 4:***

```
Due to an azure outage or maintenance
```

For more details, you can refer to this blog.

Link: https://www.cryingcloud.com/blog/2016/11/02/troubleshooting-automatic-restart-of-azure-web-jobs

## Solutions 2:

Raise a support ticket, let Microsoft help you check logs.

Comment: What if you write to D:\local\Temp, should the WebJob restart?

Comment: And moreover, is it possible to gracefully restart, implementing the same pattern as the graceful shutdown?

Comment: According to your question, I can only help you analyze the cause of webjob restart. How to restart gracefully is another question. The suggestion is to raise a support ticket and consult the official product group for the response.